# Android Facebook API error: something went wrong please try again

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

i'm sorry to repost this question, but the other one was put on hold for no reason and i have an app out there that doesn't work because of this problem, and i need a fix as soon as possible.

THIS IS THE ONLY INFO ECLIPSE AND THE APP ITSELF GIVES TO ME:

i've developed an app for android that uses fb to share a link, when i share a post with MY fb account everything goes fine, except that no one sees that post! but when i do with my gf's it doesn't even post it and gives me back a toast saying that error and logcat is this:

```
04-18 15:57:57.650: E/Activity(16658): Error: com.facebook.FacebookException: Error publishing message
```

there, i do this:

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(Favorites.this)
    .setDescription("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    .setApplicationName("xxx")
    .setName("xxx")
    .setPicture(imagesURL+filenames.get(location))
    .setLink("http://xxxxxxxxxx"+filenames.get(location))
    .build();
uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

Comment: any one else looking at this, the problem is that facebook some times consider the content url as malicious and doesn't let it post and the sdk throws this a very ambiguous exception.

Answer (score 4):

The only possible reason seems to me is that, your application is still in the **development** **mode**. If so, besides you and other administrators/testers/developers; no one can see the post and also can't publish a post via your app.

To change the mode of your app to **live** in the app settings-

[image]

Comment: Not my case because my app is live.