# Android facebook sharedialog publish return error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I try to make an facebook share from my android app.

My sharedialog is launched but i have this error on callback

```
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(25922): {"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}
```

and

```
com.facebook.FacebookException: Error publishing message
```

here is my code

```
final FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(GooglePlusActivity.this)
                        .setApplicationName(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)).setName("balbla").setLink("http://yahoo.fr").build();
                uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

thx for your help

Answer (score 1):

> com.facebook.FacebookException: Error publishing message

This is because,

*Your application is still in the development mode. If so, besides you
and other administrators/testers/developers; no one can see the post
and also can't publish a post via your app.*

Check: [android-facebook-api-error-something-went-wrong-please-try-again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155850/android-facebook-api-error-something-went-wrong-please-try-again).

> W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(25922): {"error":{"message":"An unknown
>   error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}

*You may have getting the invalid relative URL due to some null field in the URL process for the batch request. Try the null check to fix the problem.*

Answer (score 0):

"type":"OAuthException" indicates you have facebook session which is not Open / Active and same time you are trying to use facebook dialog.